# How do i solve this equation? $2^x+1=x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was just wondering if anyone could tell me how to solve the equation $2^x+1=x^2$. The integer solution is clearly $x=3$ but what method would be used to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to solve it analytically--you can only use a numerical method (which always involves guessing).  Since you're in pre-cal, I doubt you have learned any numerical methods other than guess and test.

Comment: I way to try to approximate the answer would be to graph $y=2^x+1$ and $y=x^2$ online or on a calculator and estimate the point of intersection.

Comment: You can see the function $f(x)=e^{x\log2}-x^2+1$ and study its sign and variation.

Comment: There are three solutions, with $3$ the only "nice" one.

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite as $2^x=x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$ so that if $x$ is an integer $x+1$ and $x-1$ are both powers of $2$.

Note that $(x+1)\gt(x-1)$.

Then it is clear that you must have $x+1\ge2(x-1)$ or $3\ge x$ whence it immediately follows that $x=3$ is the only positive integer solution.

---

For non-integer solutions, note that $q(x)=(x+1)(x-1)$ is nonpositive for $-1\le x\le 1$ and that $q(-1)=0$, whilst $2^x$ is always positive.

$q(-2)=3\gt2^{-2}$, so there is a solution $-2\lt x\lt -1$ by the intermediate value theorem, which can be estimated using standard methods (e.g. an iterative approach).

We also have $q(3.25)=9.5625 \gt 2^{3.25}=9.51$ - and since $2^x-q(x)$ is ultimately positive and increasing (for example for $x\ge 4$) where $2^4=16\gt q(4)=15$ there is another solution with $3.25\lt x\lt 4$, as well as the solution $x=3$. And there are no solutions for $x\ge 4$.

There is a little more work to do to show that there are only three solutions.

Answer (score 1):

$$2^x=(x+1)(x-1)$$
LHS has multiple of $2$. In RHS difference between two factors is $2$. If we look at the powers of $2$, they are $2,4,8,16,\cdots$ The difference each term is increasing. Only power having difference $2$ are $2$ & $4$. Hence $x+1=4$ & $x-1=2$. Thus, $x=3$ is the only answer.

Let me note that for negative integers LHS will be less than $1$ and greater than $0$ but RHS will be an integer so it will not give the solution.

Comment: That explains it quite well thank you! However there a also two other non - integer solutions. could you explain how I would solve for them? Thanks!

Comment: By drawing graphs of 2^x & x^2+1 & finding intersection will give the solution i guess.